# Ant task for easier deployment

Tags: java, ant

We have quite a big tree of source code, parts of it are deployed as two separate jar files. We need an easy control of what goes to which jar.

So far we do this by `<exclude name="" />` and `<include name="" />` tags, but this is quite inconvenient. The best option would be a separate config file with all the packages listed which we could comment out when needed, say  with a '#' character.

Does something similar exist or do we have to write a new ant task that reads such a file and runs a `<jar>` task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANT `includes` and `excludes` can be managed with external files and **[referenced in a fileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html)** using `includesfile` and `excludesfile` attributes.

> **includesfile**      the name of a file; each
>   line of this file is taken to be an
>   include pattern.
>   **excludesfile**  the
>   name of a file; each line of this file
>   is taken to be an exclude pattern.

For example:

```
 <jar destfile="${dist}/lib/app1.jar">
   <fileset dir=".">
    <includesfile name="app1.properties"/>
   </fileset>
  </jar>
 <jar destfile="${dist}/lib/app2.jar">
   <fileset dir=".">
    <includesfile name="app2.properties"/>
   </fileset>
  </jar>
```

Answer (score 3):

The best option would bee to seperate the code into different modules which can be build on their own (of course with dependencies to each other). Doing this also makes cyclic dependencies obvious and gives you the chance to optimize your code base.